# Update ongoing notification every 60 seconds

Tags: android, alarmmanager

A core functionality of my app is that it has an ongoing notification with a countdown timer that updates every minute - even if the app gets shut down by Android OS.

First I was using a service to run the timer and update the notification, but this was a memory/battery hog. So I switched to using `AlarmManager` to finish the timer and a repeating alarm to wake up every 60 seconds or so to update the notification:

```
Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
repeatingIntent.putExtra(PERFORM_ACTION, ALARM_ACTION_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION);
PendingIntent repeatingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 
       REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION, repeatingIntent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);       
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000, 
    REPEATING_ALARM_INTERVAL*1000, repeatingAlarmIntent);
```

This works on most devices I've tried it on (and it's much kinder on RAM/battery/CPU) but on Galaxy S6 for example, the repeating alarm is being triggered only every 5 minutes or even less frequently. It sometimes get triggered on time when the device is plugged in but it is very inconsistent. I've tried setting the repeating interval to 30 seconds or less, but it has no effect, the alarm is not triggered (I see every time it's triggered in LogCat). Other, non-repeating alarms are triggered on time.

What would be a good way to ensure that the ongoing notification is updated at least every 60 seconds come hell or high water? Other than going back to using a service (ugh! plus the OS sometimes outright kills the service on devices with little RAM), the only other thing that comes to mind is to set like 5 different repeating alarms (with different request codes) and have each one trigger every 5 minutes in a staggered fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setRepeating()` use [`setExact()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) or [`setWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and set a new alarm each time it's fired. This works well above API19.

Comment: That should work, but it would create a chain and if one alarm failed to go off the chain would be broken. Would that be an issue? I'm not sure how reliable alarms are, as I don't know whether they're ignored or delayed by the OS when they misfire.

Comment: They shouldn't misfire... you could set an alarm at 60 and 120 seconds, so if one misfires, it's not a big deal? I haven't really seen the `setExact()` alarms misfire in practice, however.

Comment: After so many years and so many hundreds of thousands of users, I can confirm that this is the best way to do as far as I know. I should have accepted this answer ages ago but I just forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

> even if the app gets shut down by Android OS

No luck. When app gets killed by OS then it is dead and will not be able to do  much, incl. posting notification.

> being triggered only every 5 minutes or even less frequentl

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html says:

"*Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use.*"

More on this also here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Not services but alarms. When I kill the app, the alarms stay and wake up the app for like 1/100 seconds to update the notification or finish the timer and create a new notification or whatever. I've tried this using several apps that kill apps/processes. Everything works fine except on some devices repeating alarms don't trigger at set intervals but later. I would prefer an elegant solution, but I want my users to get what they want from the app, no matter what Google says.

Comment: @TimSim correct. I removed that portion of my answer.

Comment: Nonetheless, the alarms never get deleted no matter what I do with the app (if I kill it using some app, or on low RAM devices use other apps to get the OS to shut down my app). The alarm triggers, wakes up my app (specifically AlarmReceiver class), then my app updates the notification and goes to sleep again. The only way I know to delete those alarms (other than having my app do it) is to reboot the device.

Comment: @TimSim If you stop the app with "Force stop" button in system settings, your alarms will be removed.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. Still, that doesn't happen when the OS shuts down the app to reclaim resources and that's my main concern. I can't have users complaining that my app randomly shut down when it's not even my fault.

Comment: Sure, that's not your fault. Yet the question was about inexact alarm fires. Have you tried altering your code according to docs I pointed to?

Comment: I've read all those documents when I was first setting up the alarms and have followed the recommendations to the best of my abilities. I don't see what I could change to have the alarm trigger every 60 seconds (or more often, as long as the notification shows the approximately correct number of minutes). Looks like Google's response would be I shouldn't need that.